# PostgreSQL call function returning setof record with table and additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I am trying to call a function returning all columns of an existing table + some unrelated additional ones and retrieve the returned data using the following syntax:

```
select *
from test_func(...)
as (a_table my_table_name, rows_count numeric);
```

The function has the following format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_func(...)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    
DECLARE
    _sql VARCHAR;
begin
    
    _sql := 'SELECT mtn.*, count(*) over() as rows_count  
        from public.my_table_name mtn
        ... inner joins and other stuff';

    return query
    execute _sql using ..._sql params...;

END;
$function$
;
```

However, it doesn't work. The error I receive:

```
ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type numeric does not match expected type "my_table_name" in column 1.
```

Comment: Instead of SELECT mtn.*, use the actual column name that contains the table name

Comment: @Shameel I don't understand. How do I select all the table columns then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query in your function should return a `my_table_name` (a “whole-row reference), you should write it like

```
SELECT mtn, count(*) OVER () ...
```